# sending large object from ViewController to another in Objective C, ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to get a JSON object from website in one view controller : `QRViewController.m`

I wanna show the result in another view controller `ImagePreviewViewController.m`

so the object that i want to send of type : `RetrievedJSONObject`

```
@interface RetrievedJSONObject : NSObject


@property NSString *_id;
@property NSString *nfcId;
@property NSString *company;
@property NSString *qrId;
@property NSString *address;
@property NSString *mimeType;
@property NSString *url;
@property NSString *content;

- (void) nsLogitAll;
- (void) nsLogitWithoutContent;
- (NSData *) getContentAsData;

- (id) init;
- (id) initWithId:(NSString *) o_id :(NSString *)o_nfcId :(NSString *)o_company :(NSString *)o_address :(NSString *)o_mimeType :(NSString *)o_url :(NSString*)o_content;

@end
```

The `NSString *content` is sometimes a byte array and relatively has large size.

**Question 1:** is it effecient to send such large object by segue?

**Question 2:** I tried to make **static** variable in `ImagePreviewViewController` the one that will recieve, and i want to initialize it instead of sending it by segue. but here also i had issue with how to create static object in Objective-C ?

Comment: In my point of view its efficient to send such large object by segue.

Comment: You aren't really sending anything. Large, small, it makes no difference because all you are doing is passing a reference to the data.

Comment: @dandan78 it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a property in the destination controller and assign it in the `prepareForSegue` method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ImagePreviewViewController *vc = (ImagePreviewViewController*)
      [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.jsonObject = retrievedJSONObject;
}
```

If you don't copy the data, you will have one single instance of that large string in memory, so you shouldn't have memory issues. You can declare the property in the destination controller as follow:

```
@interface ImagePreviewViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) RetrievedJSONObject *jsonObject;
@end
```

Comment: so this code doesnt copy the object? just references ?

Comment: the object is not copied as the property doesn't have the `copy` attribute